# Setting varible in action class and fetching value in JSP using struts2

Tags: struts2

I am calling struts2 action class through a ajax call from javascript, which redirect it to b.jsp on success return. In action class I am setting a parameter called dummyValue, for which i have defined getter and setter in the action class. But when i try to display the value of this dummyValue using  it does not shows any value.

struts.xml

```
<package name="AbcAction" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
<action name="abcAction" class="com.AbcAction">
    <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">stream</param>
</result>
<result name="input" type="dispatcher">/errorPage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Setting the result type as stream on purpose.

AbcAction class

```
 public class AbcAction extends ActionSupport  {
        private InputStream stream;
        private String dummyValue;
      public String execute() {
    dummyValue = "Hello";
           try
               String str = "success";
           stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        return SUCCESS;
} 
    catch (Exception e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();

    String str = "error";
                 stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    return ERROR;
} 

}
public InputStream getStream() {
    return stream;
}
public void setStream(InputStream stream) {
    this.stream = stream;
}
public String getDummyValue() {
    return dummyValue;
}
        public void setDummyValue(String dummyValue) {
    this.dummyValue = dummyValue;
}
```

}

Javascript function to call action class

```
function callAbcAction()  {

$.ajax({
                url : "abcAction",
                type: 'post',

                 data: { },

                   success : function(result){
                   if (result == "success") {
            window.location='b.jsp';
                  }
                 else {
            window.location='errorPage';
                 }
             },
           });
```

}

Tag to print dummyMsg in b.jsp

```
       <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Dummy Value is : <s:property value="dummyValue"/></p>
        </div>
```

It is redirecting to b.jsp on success return, but println only "Dummy Value is : " no value is coming.

Please help.

Thanks,
Savvy

Comment: Show me more how did you redirect on jsp.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling b.jsp directly. Also this isn't a server redirect but one handled by the client... It is like you are making a new request from scratch, of course the server isn't going to know anything about the previous request (http being stateless and all), unless you pass what you want along with the request (another ajax call with payload or passing along url params).

Comment: Thanks  @Quaternion.

Comment: Well since you understand the issue, you can handle it from the client, but if you know you need to redirect struts2 can do this in several different ways (search for "struts2 redirect, chain") there are quite a few good answers on here that pertain to this.